# XPages custom validator

Tags: xpages

Ultimately I need to do some cross field validation and thought I would use a custom validator to do this. But I can't even get a simple example to work. The following code (which is pretty similar to that on p.116 of "Mastering XPages" allows any value (including an empty field). Am I missing something obvious?

```
            <xp:inputText
                id="field1"
                value="#{document1.field1}">
                <xp:this.validators>
                    <xp:customValidator>
                        <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (value == "") {
return new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Please enter a value");
}}]]></xp:this.validate>
                    </xp:customValidator>
                </xp:this.validators>
            </xp:inputText>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to validate an empty field with a validator. A validator runs only if a value exist. In XPages you have the *required* property for fields which allows to check for empty fields; this is a workaround for this problem, and it is (as far as I know) not possible to create your own "required" validator.

If you want to create your own one, you have to create a converter instead

**UPDATE 21.06.2013**

It is possible to create an own *required validator* with a small workaround: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=764

Comment: FacesMessage works fine for me as well as string. I suggested an edit to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I ultimately need to do is some cross-field validation. I know I can compute the _required_ property, but am having trouble referring to the value of another field in the computed formula. I have tried both options in the following code snippet but neither trigger the field1 validation. Any thoughts on the _best_ way to achieve this? if (document1.getItemValueString("field2") == "Maintenance") {
//if (getComponent("field2").getSubmittedValue() == "Maintenance") {
 return true;
} else {
 return false;
}

Comment: Ah - I need to .getValue() rather than .getSubmittedValue(). Also I see that FacesMessage _does_ work when the validator checking against a real value rather than an empty field. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a string with the error message in it - and not a FacesMessage object.

So in your case, do this instead:

```
<xp:inputText id="field1" value="#{document1.field1}">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:customValidator>
            <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                if (value == "") {
                    return "Please enter a value";
                }
            }]]></xp:this.validate>
        </xp:customValidator>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
```