# Cannot get Custom Validator to fire

Tags: xpages

I am stumped.  I have an input field in an xpage where I added a custom validator.  I can not get the custom validator to fire no matter what I try.   There is a also validateRequired which works as expected.  The error message is sent to a "Display Error" control, clientside validation is disabled.   The goal of the custom validator is to check if a valid date has been entered.  After I get it working, I also plan to add other complicated validation such as checking valid day of the week.

The print statements work correctly, as in "inside true" shows in the console for a valid date, and "inside false" shows for an invalid date.   If I add a test print statement after the if statement, it doesn't not execute as you would think.  For either condition, the message does not display, and the page is submitted.

I have tried using both getValue() and getSubmittedValue.  I have also tried returning a facesMessage and a string.  I am also very open to better ways to do this.

```
<xp:inputText id="datepicker" styleClass="datepicker" 
value="#{viewScope.arrivalDate}" 
defaultValue="#{javascript:statusBean.arrivalDate}"
disableClientSideValidation="true">
      <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired message="Please enter the arrival date">
        </xp:validateRequired>
        <xp:customValidator message="err" loaded="true">
            <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:var datepicker = getComponent("datepicker").getSubmittedValue();
            var testDate = @IsTime(@TextToTime(datepicker));
            print("testDate=" + testDate);
            if(testDate == 0){
             print("inside false");
             return false;
        } else if(testDate == 1){
             print("inside true");
             return true;
            }}]]>
           </xp:this.validate>
        </xp:customValidator>
     </xp:this.validators>
```

Comment: For me `customValidator` stopped working suddenly in 8.5.2FP3 and I had to change it to `this.validator` as shown by Paul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried with a custom validator, but here's the SSJS I put in the validator property for a sample demo at LUGs last year:

```
<xp:this.validator>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:var sv = this.getSubmittedValue();
print ("Checking submitted value for input1 '" + sv + "' is more than 5 characters");
print ("Value for input1 is " + this.getValue());
if (sv.length < 5) {
    var msgStr = "You must enter your FULL name, which will be more than 5 characters!";
    var msgObj = new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msgStr, msgStr);
    facesContext.addMessage(getClientId(this.getId()), msgObj);
    this.setValid(false);
}}]]>
</xp:this.validator>
```

Note that it adds the facesMessage and also sets the component's valid property to false.

Answer (score 3):

The customValidator must return a string with the error message in it - and not true or false.

So in your case, do this instead:

```
<xp:customValidator message="err" loaded="true">
    <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var datepicker = getComponent("datepicker").getSubmittedValue();
        var testDate = @IsTime(@TextToTime(datepicker));
        print("testDate=" + testDate);
        if(testDate == 0){
            print("inside false");
            return "Invalid date";
        }
    }]]></xp:this.validate>
</xp:customValidator>
```

Comment: This does not work.   @Per I actually saw a comment from you in response to a similar question, and tried it before I asked the question.   Today, I tried it all over again.   The print is executed meaning the if was true, but nothing was returned to the <xp:messages>, and the form was submitted.  The vaildateRequired works as expected.

Comment: Trying <xp:message> instead of <xp:messages> made no difference.

Comment: what if you return a facesMessage object instead? return new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Invalid date"); Also notice this comment from Sven that validators can not validate empty values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609867/xpages-custom-validator

Comment: I tried that too, but will try again.  The post you linked to is what I used yesterday to troubleshoot.  If it was empty then the required validator will fire, and it does.  When I put junk in, then I want it to fire.  Could it be the @functions, they seem to be working as they should???

Comment: No it won't work using FacesMessage.   It won't even work if I only include the line "return new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Invalid date");"  I know the code is executing since my print statements work.  I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Thanks Per for your help!  This obviously must have worked for others (based on up votes),  but for me the validator worked as Paul suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version with using xSnippet - postValidationError.

```
<xp:customValidator>
    <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if (@IsTime(@TextToTime(@Trim(value))) == 0){
          postValidationError(this, "Please enter a valid Date/Time")
        } 
    }]]></xp:this.validate>
</xp:customValidator>
```

Comment: Looks like this is a global function that effectively does the same thing. I'd recommend using this if you're heavily using SSJS (it's less typing).