# required property on xp:inputText blocks computed rendered property on other controls

Tags: java, xpages

In my XPage I compute the rendered property of some controls e.g

```
<xp:panel rendered="#{employeeBean.senior}"></xp:panel>
```

After I added on a control the property

```
required="true"
```

these rendered properties no longer work, unless I submit the document and the form is validated.

When I apply a custom formvalidator according to the guidelines provided here:

[adding validation to my save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217207/adding-validation-to-my-save-method)

the rendered properties work as expected.

My questions are:

- Why is the default required=true property "blocking" my rendered proporties? -
- How can I prevent this?
- How can I use the required property with the computed rendered property since this is a time-saver for me?

Answer (score 0):

`required="true"` shouldn't be preventing the rendered property working. However, it will prevent the normal partial refresh lifecycle completing and therefore the data model being updated. A normal partial refresh lifecycle runs through Process Validations (phase 3), which runs all converters and validators to ensure validity of the text values entered in the browser (and passed to the components' `submittedValue` property in Apply Request Values phase, phase 2). If this fails for any component, the partial refresh lifecycle immediately skips to Render Response, the sixth and last phase, returning the validation error to the browser to be displayed in a Display Error / Display Errors component (so always include that in the refresh area). It never runs Update Model Values phase (phase 4) which passed the values to the `value` property of each component, now that they have been validated and confirmed that they can be converted to whatever underlying data type they are to be stored as. And it never runs Invoke Application (phase 5) which runs your Java / SSJS.

Your rendered property points to a Java variable which still has the *last valid entered value*.

On the partial refresh, `disableValidators="true"` ("Process data without validation") can be used to skip validation, and the data model will be updated. If there are conversion errors (e.g. "One" entered into a number field), it will still fail, because to update the data model with that value would break everything.

Putting the validation in the save button works, because the validation isn't running during every partial refresh, just during the save. That's why I typically prefer that option.

Here is one option for ease of mandatory fields, if your Java beans typically extend the Map interface. If you have another property in the bean with keys mapping to the properties that are mandatory and values mapping to the display label, you could use that in a validation routine on your save. If the bean extends Map, you can call:

```
for (String propName : requiredProperties.keySet()) {
  if (StringUtil.isEmpty(get(propName)) {
    // throw error message using FacesMessage, possibly try to invalidate component as well
  }
}
```

For more on the refresh lifecycle, there are various sessions on my [Slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/paulswithers1) from conferences where I've covered this, and also a [TLCC webinar](http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/recorded-xpages-webinars) last year, "Marty, You're Just Not thinking Fourth Dimensionally".